# Determine which code will run when a button is pressed - limit checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, checkbox

I have this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/elenderg/wzarrg06/63/

There are 10 buttons on first div.
[image: buttons]

```
    <button class='btn btn-info custom' onclick="myFunction()">6 (R$ 2,00)</button>
    <button class='btn btn-info custom' onclick="myFunction()">7 (R$ 5,00)</button>
    <button class='btn btn-info custom' onclick="myFunction()">8 (R$ 10,00)</button>
    <button class='btn btn-info custom' onclick="myFunction()">9 (R$ 20,00)</button>
    <button class='btn btn-info custom' onclick="myFunction()">10 (R$ 50,00)</button>
    <button class='btn btn-info custom' onclick="myFunction()">11 (R$ 100,00)</button>
    <button class='btn btn-info custom' onclick="myFunction()">12 (R$ 250,00)</button>
    <button class='btn btn-info custom' onclick="myFunction()">13 (R$ 500,00)</button>
    <button class='btn btn-info custom' onclick="myFunction()">14 (R$ 1000,00)</button>
    <button class='btn btn-info custom' onclick="myFunction()">15 (R$ 2000,00)</button>
```

they will determine how many checkboxes users will be able to select on div #2 (e.g if user click on "6" button he shall only be able to click on 6 checkboxes)
[image: checkboxes]

I need a js/jquery code to limit how many checkboxes can be selected based in which button is clicked.

Comment: We need you to show us what you have tried

Comment: there is a javascript code on my jsfiddle .but it requires every checkbox to have a different name, I'm looking forother solution.

Comment: function KeepCount() {

var NewCount = 0

if (document.selecao.myTextEditBox.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1}


if (NewCount == 7)
{
alert('Você  já escolheu seis dezenas"')
document.selecao; return false;
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward using jQuery.  I've created a simple dummied down example:

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="limits">
    <input type="button" value="Three" data-value="3">
    <input type="button" value="Four" data-value="4">
    <input type="button" value="Five" data-value="5">
<div>

<div class="checks">
    <input type="checkbox" name=“check” id="check1" value="1" />
    <label for="check1">1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name=“check” id="check2" value="2" />
    <label for="check2">2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name=“check” id="check3" value="3" />
    <label for="check3">3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name=“check” id="check4" value="4" />
    <label for="check4">4</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name=“check” id="check5" value="5" />
    <label for="check5">5</label>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
(function($){

    var currentLimit=3;

    $('div.limits > input[type=button]').on('click',function(){
      currentLimit = parseInt($(this).data('value'));
    });

    $('div.checks input').on('click', function(e){
        var totalChecked = $('input:checked').length;

        if (totalChecked > currentLimit){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

})(jQuery)
```

And here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jh5wtzaf/

Comment: I should also note, you'll need to handle in the UI if the user changes the limit.  For instance, if they have more checkboxes than the new limit allows.   I didn't include it as it was not part of the OP.

Comment: can you give me more details in how to handle UI?

Comment: A lot of ways to solve this. Probably the easiest is to prompt the user to reset all checks if the limit selected is less than current total of boxes checked.